# How to implement facebook like using graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Should this work:

- Create 'object' under facebook app
- Authorize user with 'publish_action' permission
- Call `FB.api( "/{object-id}/likes", "POST", ... )` in javascript

where `{object-id}` is the ID of the created object (not concatenated with anything else).

That's broadly what I'm attempting to do, but it doesn't work.

I'm getting follow error:

> The parameter url is required
>   OAuthException
>   100

Am I just taking the wrong approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your approach is absolutely fine.

You must be using a wrong `object_id`. I'm not sure what object id are you using, but the object id could be a `post id`, `comment id` etc.; it could not be a page id.